# controller does not recognize routeParams variable passed from routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-routing

```
  <script>
    var app= angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngResource']);

    app.factory('Greeter', ['$resource',function($resource){
      return $resource(
        'http://123.com/processor-url.php',{
        },{
          query: {
            method:'GET',
            /*params: { myvar: myvarActual },*/
            isArray:true

          }
        }
      );
    }]);

    app
    .controller('appointmentController', ['$scope', 'Greeter',function($scope,$routeParams,Greeter){
      alert($routeParams.myvar);
      Greeter.query(function(data) {
        $scope.output = data.myvar;
      });

    }]);

    app.controller('homeController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    }])


    /*Final Config After Loading Everything*/
    app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
      $routeProvider.when('/appointments/:myvar', {templateUrl: 'appointments.html', controller: 'appointmentController'});
      $routeProvider.when('/home', {templateUrl: 'home.html', controller: 'homeController'});
      $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: '/home'});
    }]);
  </script>
```

In the above code, seems the controler is not even recognize `myvar` that was suppose to be included in the `routeProvider's myvar`. As the alert will show `undefined`, instead of the actually value of `myvar` (i.e. ...`/appointments/1066` ... if so I expect `$routeParams.myvar = 1066`, and `alert($routeParams.myvar)` should be 1066

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$routeParams` is missing from the dependency declaration so currently it's looking for `myvar` on `Greeter` which doesn't exist...

```
app
.controller('appointmentController', ['$scope', 'Greeter',function($scope,$routeParams,Greeter){
```

Should be...

```
app
.controller('appointmentController', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Greeter', function($scope, $routeParams, Greeter){
```